# Is x--->y a trivial functional dependency?

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

If y is a subset of x then x-->y is trivial functional dependency (it is well known). But I have doubt: y is not subset of x and x U y = R, then can I say x-->y is a trivial functional dependency.( I read it in some article)

Adding to above question: Why X U Y = R holds in case of multivalued dependencies(trivial)? Can somebody give an example so that I can understand?

Comment: could you provide a link to that article?

Comment: In case of multivalued dependencies it holds. An MVD x --->> y in R is called a trivial MVD if a) Y is a subset of X or b) x U y = R.I applied it for functional dependencies also. I got confused.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Suppose R is {a1, a2} x is a1 and y is a2. x U y = R holds, but x-->y is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 0):

**Trivial functional dependency**

No it is not a trivial functional. It is only a trivial functional dependency when a subset of attributes depends from the full set.

Definition of trivial functional dependency:

[image: Trivial functional dependency]

Eg.: (a,b) depends from (a,b,c) attributes.

In you case it is not a subset, so it is not a trivial functional dependency.

What you described is a key candidate. *(X depends from itself (trivial), and it also determines all the other part, so this way the whole relation)*

**Multivalued dependencies**

Multivalues dependencies can be threathed like it was some more general version of functional dependencies. 
Some help:

[Multivalued dependencies on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency)

You can even find some examples there and also the formal definition.